# How to use the return true/false in js

Tags: javascript

I have a function, for example check navigator params, like that :

```
function paramsDevice() { 
    if ( navigator.userAgent. etc ... ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

how to use the return, in a other part of js code ?

```
if (paramsDevice == false)
```

not working and i have no error

Comment: Did you get it clearly ?

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are comparing undefined variable `paramsDevice` with the boolean `false`.To compare returned by `paramsDevice()` value try the following :

```
if (paramsDevice() == false)
```

You can also assign a variable to the result to use it in the `if` statement :

```
var paramsDevice = paramsDevice()
if (paramsDevice == false)
```

Comment: Please explain him the difference, as he is clearly a beginner at Javascript.

Comment: thks for the response ;)

Comment: @JoDiii:Have you succeeded?

Answer (score 1):

use `===` to compare with `false` .You can assign your function a variable.Then you can check the variable `if (paramsDevice == false)`

```
var paramsDevice = function() {
    if (1 === true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};


if (paramsDevice === false) {
alert('working....');
}
```

[**WORKING Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aSDxC/)